# output_data[output_ids == i] = input_data[input_ids == i] in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In numpy code, if you want same id to get same value, you can for example:

```
input_data = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
input_ids = np.array([0, 1, 2])
output_ids = np.array([2, 0, 1, 0])
output_data = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
for i in input_ids:
    output_data[output_ids == i] = input_data[input_ids == i]
print(output_data)
```

**Output:[0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1]**

Note: input_ids = unique(input_ids), it is unique at the beginning.

while in tensorflow， how can I perform this kind of code, which fuction shall I use. Any similar example?

- input_data: a tensor, can be float64, float 32
- output_data: a tensor, same type as input_data
- input_ids: a tensor, has to be int32 or int64.
- output_ids: a tensor, has to be int32 or int64.

Comment: The initial values in `output_data` are not used in any way for the result, right? Also, are the `input_ids` always sorted like that? That is, is it always a vector like `[0, 1, 2, ...]`?

Comment: @jdehesa no, it is not specified to be sorted .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you a few options in order of ascending complexity. In the simplest case `input_ids` is always a sequence of integers starting from `0`, corresponding to the indices of `input_data` (`[0, 1, 2, ...]`). In that case you can simply do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    input_data = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    output_ids = tf.constant([2, 0, 1, 0])
    output_data = tf.gather(input_data, output_ids)
    print(sess.run(output_data))
    # [0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1]
```

If `input_ids` does not correspond to the indices of `input_data`, but it is still sorted in ascending order, you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    input_data = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    input_ids = tf.constant([-2, 0, 4])
    output_ids = tf.constant([4, -2, 0, -2])
    output_idx = tf.searchsorted(input_ids, output_ids)
    output_data = tf.gather(input_data, output_idx)
    print(sess.run(output_data))
    # [0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1]
```

The most general case is where `input_ids` is an unsorted array of integers. In that case you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    input_data = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    input_ids = tf.constant([3, 1, 6])
    output_ids = tf.constant([6, 3, 1, 3])
    # From TF v1.13
    s = tf.argsort(input_ids)
    # Before TF v1.13
    s = tf.contrib.framework.argsort(input_ids)
    output_idx_s = tf.searchsorted(tf.gather(input_ids, s), output_ids)
    output_data = tf.gather(input_data, tf.gather(s, output_idx_s))
    print(sess.run(output_data))
    # [0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1]
```

Of course, in all cases you can use the quadratic solution of comparing every value in `input_ids` to every value in `output_ids`. I will write it below for reference but is less efficient in time and memory than the previous ones, so there is really no reason to prefer it.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    input_data = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    input_ids = tf.constant([3, 1, 6])
    output_ids = tf.constant([6, 3, 1, 3])
    eq = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(output_ids, 1), input_ids)
    output_idx = tf.argmax(tf.cast(eq, tf.int8), axis=1)
    output_data = tf.gather(input_data, output_idx)
    print(sess.run(output_data))
    # [0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1]
```

EDIT: As [giser_yugang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7389608) points out, there could also be the case where not all the values in `output_ids` are in `input_ids`. In that case the initial values for `output_data` would be used. You could implement that with something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    input_data = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
    input_ids = tf.constant([3, 1, 6])
    output_data = tf.constant([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
    output_ids = tf.constant([6, 3, 1, 3, 0])
    # From TF v1.13
    s = tf.argsort(input_ids)
    # Before TF v1.13
    s = tf.contrib.framework.argsort(input_ids)
    input_ids_s = tf.gather(input_ids, s)
    n = tf.size(input_ids)
    output_idx_s = tf.minimum(tf.searchsorted(input_ids_s, output_ids), n - 1)
    output_data = tf.where(tf.equal(output_ids, tf.gather(input_ids_s, output_idx_s)),
                           tf.gather(input_data, tf.gather(s, output_idx_s)),
                           output_data)
    print(sess.run(output_data))
    # [0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1 0. ]
```

Comment: I am also concerned about this question.Your answer is really perfect. I want to ask what if there is an ID in `output_ids` that is not included in `input_ids`? Maybe I should ask a new question?

Comment: @giser_yugang That's a good point, yes that is a possible case too. I have added another alternative for that. If you feel that deserves its own question feel free to post it, and if you want use the code above in a self-answer.

Comment: It seems that `tf.size(input_ids)-1` should be used instead of `tf.size(input_ids)` when `output_ids = tf.constant([6, 3, 1, 3, 8])`. You answered my question perfectly. It worked like a charm.

Comment: @giser_yugang That's correct, thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: @jdehesa HUGE THX!! Now I am testing the code.Is tf.searchsort() is only available for 1.13?[tensorflow search](https://www.tensorflow.org/s/results/?q=searchsorted%201.9&p=%2F). So I think I shall set a conda env for tensorflow 1.13?

Comment: @TinaLiu It is in TF 1.12 too (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/searchsorted)), you could upgrade to either. Note however that if you are using GPU/CUDA, TF 1.13 has changed the dependency to CUDA 10 instead of CUDA 9.

Comment: @jdehesa I have installed TF1.13 with cudatoolkit=9.0 in conda and the conda didnt remind of cuda10. And simple code work. Thank you. I think I should try 1.12.