# tensorflow how to use tf.map_fn to process two input tensor shape of (?, 40,30,128) and (?,40,30) in batch wise, ? is my batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TF1.12.

I got a function input size is `fn([40, 30, 128],[40, 30])` and return `tf.float32`

But with batch size, I don't know what to do. Then I found this [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) `tf.map_fn`. I got two input so where shall I put my input.
`input1 [?, 40, 30, 128]`and `input2 [?, 40, 30]`

The batch size is `None`, but they are equal.

Anything related will be thankful. I am new to tensorflow, so anything is helpful.

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
tf.map_fn(lambda inp: fn(inp[0], inp[1]), (input1, input2))
```

Note that [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) is generally slower than using a vectorized solution. Consider whether you can make `fn` work with batches of data instead of with individual batch elements.

Comment: It worked perfectly, anyway my next step is totally vectorized solution. You know few days ago, I was freak out about tensorflow, cause it is really different from normal language, you can't use `for`, you could only use API provided by TF and there is a lot of them!! You answered my first question[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073800/output-dataoutput-ids-i-input-datainput-ids-i-in-tensorflow) You just not only give me the perfect answer, but also give me profound advice. Thank you sooooo much. You are a great tutor. Now I love tensorflow.

Comment: @TinaLiu Glad it helped, thank you for the kind words. TensorFlow can indeed be challenging, do not feel discouraged if you have a hard time with its atypical programming model, it is difficult for everyone. Eager mode and TensorFlow 2.x are supposed to make that somewhat easier (although I personally feel more comfortable with "classic" TensorFlow now that I'm used to it). Anyway hopefully you will get the hang of it soon.